# How can I build a regression for this linear model?

Tags: r, linear-regression, finance, stock, hypothesis-test

I have the following linear model, for which I want to build a regression.

[i,t] = [i]+[i][m,t] +[i][m,t][t]+[i,t]

r[i,t] and r[m,t] are the returns of financial data at time t and an equity index [i] or market[m],  d[t] is a dummy variable which takes value 1 after a specific event and value 0 before the event.  is an error term.
the null hypothesis is H0: y[i] = 0;
a rejection would mean H1a : y[i] < 0 or H1b: y[i] > 0

I'm not sure how to implement the y in my regression.

I would really appreciate your help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to say without seeing your data, but looks like this could be expressed as a fixed effects model, where you have an interaction between `R_{m,t}` and `D_{t}`.  However, there isn't really enough information to explain exactly how to implement this without more information about your model and data.

You can find an example of how this is implemented [on this website (Econometrics with R)](https://www.econometrics-with-r.org/10-3-fixed-effects-regression.html) in general, with several approaches and functions (e.g. `plm` vesus `lm`, within versus first-difference).